# map of europe in list of lat/long points

Tags: web-mapping

I'm looking for a list of lat/long coordinates which will describe all countries of europe. Ideally the list will also describe on which country each closed path belongs to. I'm imagining something along the lines:

```
 lat    long    cc  type
------ ------- ---- ----
55.05   -7.25   IE  EU27
55.18   -6.97   IE  EU27
55.25   -6.48   IE  EU27
55.22   -6.1    IE  EU27
55.05   -6      IE  EU27
54.83   -5.7    IE  EU27
54.63   -5.92   IE  EU27
...         
55.23   -6.93   IE  EU27
55.05   -7.25   IE  EU27

58.63   -5      UK  EU27
58.55   -4.67   UK  EU27
58.45   -4.77   UK  EU27
58.58   -4.6    UK  EU27
58.45   -4.48   UK  EU27
58.6    -4.02   UK  EU27
58.63   -3.02   UK  EU27
58.37   -3.12   UK  EU27
57.85   -4.2    UK  EU27
57.85   -3.77   UK  EU27
57.6    -4.42   UK  EU27
57.6    -4.1    UK  EU27
...
```

Regarding accuracy, I'd be happy with anything over 5.000 points in total.

Where should I look at?

I will convert those coordinates to x/y using `fromLatLngToContainerPixel` of google maps and then draw the map using javascript.

Comment: Why? ... What's the use of doing it this way?

Comment: I want to create the map in paper.js (http://paperjs.org/). I want to be able to draw it on a `<canvas />` element so I have full control of what I'm doing and not depend on third party mapping libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One source for this is [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/). It provides data for country boundaries at several detail levels.

The vector data is provided as shapefiles, which could be converted into the format that you want.

Comment: Any idea on which file specifically to look at?

Comment: Probably the "Admin 0 - Countries" data from the medium scale (1:50m) cultural data.

Answer (score 1):

There is some data in GoogleFusionTables: 
[Europe Country Boundaries](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1zRwLHfV_PEaqY4mTWamboV3M7nzL29n_OmMKuZA#rows%3aid=1). 
Not really exactly as you want.. meaning formating, but I guess you won't have so much problems to fix that.

Or another source, that provides KML, so just reading data from there...
http://www.gadm.org/

Hope, that helps!

Comment: Thanks. The GoogleFusionTables was nice (formatting is not a problem) but it's of very low granularity. For example it just gives around 20 points for small countries and that defines a rough country boundary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still hard pressed to find this:

Find polygons of your countries of interest, convert to raster with appropriate cell size, make points, add lat/long values.  You can add the rest of your fields (country, name, ISO-number, EU or no, etc).